# how can I add error checking for empty string case

Tags: c++

There is error checking for a missing file or incorrectly typed file name...but for no file_name i.e. the string file_name is empty I get the error

> `terminate` called after throwing an instance of `'std::logic_error'`

and then windows throw an error at me as well.

My guess would be to add a check for the empty string... at file_name.str() before creating an instance of type ifstream...but just wanted to check.

```
void file_to_string(string file_name)
{
    string line;  
    ifstream myfile(file_name.c_str());
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.good())
        {
            getline(myfile, line);
            cout << line;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File : " << file_name << " : did not open";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    file_to_string(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `c_str()` where you don't need to. And checking the string is easy: `file_name == ""`.

Comment: @Griwes : Pre-C++11, the standard file streams only took `char const*` arguments for the filename, so `c_str()` is indeed necessary here. Also, `file_name == ""` is the _least_ efficient approach possible, since it constructs a temporary `string` instance to compare against.

Comment: @ildjarn: The cost of the construction of the string is irrelevant. Anything you gain is lost by the cost of the IO access to the file (which cost a bazillion times more). Use std::string as it it is much safer/much easier to read and thus much easier to maintain. This is the kind of micro optimization that programers should not be worried about the compiler is good at it. Think of the overlying algorithm (the compiler is not good at that).

Comment: @Loki : How does that change the fact that there's less verbose and more efficient approaches to checking for an empty string? Just because some pointless inefficiency is outweighed by other processing costs doesn't make it any less pointless. Writing good code is not a micro-optimization.

Comment: @ildjarn: Using c_str() and strcmp() is not less verbose. It is more verbose. less readable and probably less efficient.

Comment: @Loki : Using `.empty()` _is_ more readable and more efficient.

Comment: @ildjarn: Absolutely. But that was not your original implication.

Comment: @Loki : Yes, it was, or at least it was intended to be. My mention of `.c_str()` was regarding construction of the `ifstream`. Apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: @ildjarn: Your statement that it is *the least efficient approach since is constructs a temporary string instance* is false. The standard mandates that there are overloads that take `const charT*`, so no temporary will be created. I agree that `.empty()` is quite explicit in what it does though.

Comment: @David : Fair point; I forgot `operator==` was overloaded as such, and assumed it used the implicit conversion constructor to compare two `string` instances.

Comment: @ildjarn: It would be unnecessarily bad for performance, since comparisons with literals are expected to be common in code. The precise inefficiency that you pointed out is what drives the need for the overloads.

Comment: I'm chuckling at the "string construction efficiency" debate when there's file IO to be done.  This is a classic premature optimization...

Comment: @Will : Once again, writing good code is not premature optimization. Is passing arguments by `const&` when they're only needed for readonly purposes also a premature optimization? Clearly not.

Comment: @ildjarn Like I said, I was chuckling - everyone thinks their particular premature optimization is just 'good code.'  That's part of the nature of the beast.  My only (and very narrow) point was really that regardless of how "right" one believes their particular optimization to be, the reality (in this particular case) is that any extra cycles you you've saved will be dwarfed by those taken doing file I/O.  No offense intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide an argument at all, then `argv` will only contain one string, and `argv[1]` will be invalid. You'll have to check that before you even try to access it:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    file_to_string(argv[1]);
}
```

There's no particular need to check whether the string is empty; if it is, then the file will fail to open as it would for any other invalid filename, and your code already handles that.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: ouch - more coffee required. As was clearly stated, this is a string object not a pointer.  So, use the string's provided members to verify it has content.  In practice, at the top of the file, use string.empty ala:

```
if (file_name.empty())
{
  // bug out
 cout << "Invalid filename" ;
 return;
}
```

EDIT2: As Nim correctly points out, this is not bulletproof as there could be no params supplied (and hence your reference to argv[1] will crater).  So, check these cases in main() or in another function to verify the params.

You could do something like:

```
if (argc < 2)
{
  // complain about lack of proper arguments
}
else 
{
   file_to_string(argv[1]);
}
```

All that said, in a slightly-more involved case you may face the need to add multiple different command line arguments, or for the arguments to be supplied in an arbitrary order (and so you can't rely on the index of '1' like you are here).

Handling all that properly can get fairly complicated quickly, so take a look at the approaches others have already implemented to handle this (and more - what if your options come from a config file instead of the command line?).  One such option is Boost's support for program options; see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F39%5F0/doc/html/program%5Foptions.html

Comment: `file_name == null`? what is `null`?

Comment: this is not going to help - what if `argc = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs higher than that - what if an argument (i.e. what is in `argv[1]` is crap!) is not provided? This is why you should look at proper program options utilities...